# port a variable form make to Cmake

Tags: c++, c, makefile, cmake

Our Library uses Cmake while the Overall system uses Make file for build.

I want to port the value of a variable (preprocessor macro) defined in the makefile to Cmakefile and use it as preprocessor marco in source codes of my library.

How to do that?

Comment: You'll have to tell us more about how CMake is integrated into the Makefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define variable at CMake invocation like so:

```
cmake -DMY_VAR=ON <path_to_CMakeLists.txt>
```

Then later in your CMake file:

```
if (MY_VAR)
    add_definitions(-DENABLE_MY_VAR)
endif()
```

And finally in your code:

```
#ifdef ENABLE_MY_VAR
    // Your code
#endif
```

Comment: can you please elaborate this?  cmake -DMY_VAR=ON <path_to_CMakeLists.txt>  Do I do this in makefile?

Comment: It is not clear from your question how CMake is triggered. Is it launched when you run make in the global project ?

Comment: yes ... global project is built using make...which will also trigger cmake to build our library as a shared library.

Comment: So when make launches cmake to generate makefiles, you can pass it variables based on the make variable by formatting the launch command accordingly. Adding example of the variable you want to pass on and the snippet from your makefile launching CMake will help in giving an answer.

Comment: it is sth like this                                                                                @cd $(PROJECT_DIR)/build/CMake && ./bootstrap.sh

Comment: It seems cmake invocation is done inside bootstrap.sh. Put that line and the variable you want to pass in your question.

Comment: I almost got the answer...thanks for that....how about passing a variable to cmake...tried cmake -DMY_VAR=5 <path_to_CMakeLists.txt>, but could not figure out how to get that variable in the source code..

Comment: actually, i want to pass the variable itself (its a number) not switch...I want to do sth like cmake -DMY_VAR=5<path_to_CMakeLists.txt>. I tried add_definitions(-DMY_VAR) or add_definitions(-DMY_VAR_NEW=MY_VAR) in CMake file, but did not work :(